# Load data dynamically when I change the date

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

This is my calendar object

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
            calendar: {
                height: 450,
                editable: false,
                header: {
                    left: 'title',
                    center: '',
                    right: 'today prev,next'
                },
                eventClick: $scope.onEventClick,
                eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
                eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
                eventRender: $scope.eventRender,
                dayClick: $scope.onDayClick,
                viewRender: $scope.getData
            }
        };
```

and

```
     $scope.getData = function(view, element){
            $scope.intervalStartDate = new Date(view.start);
            $scope.intervalEndDate = new Date(view.end);

        $scope.managedEvents = Event.getFittingsForDateInterval({
            intervalStartDate : convertDate($scope.intervalStartDate),
            intervalEndDate : convertDate($scope.intervalEndDate)
        });

$scope.managedEvents.$promise.then(function(data){
    $scope.uiConfig.calendar.events = data;
});

    }
```

if I remove

```
$scope.uiConfig.calendar.events = data;
```

no data is populating and if i include that it is refreshing and loading current month data

for the first time it is loading the data for January month, whenever I click on next month icon, it is calling for February month data and again calendar is resetting to present month (it is calling $scope.getData again)

```
data = [{start : some_date, end : some_date, title : event_name},{start : some_date, end : some_date, title : event_name},{start : some_date, end : some_date, title : event_name},{start : some_date, end : some_date, title : event_name},{start : some_date, end : some_date, title : event_name}];
```

I want to get data for only current view instead of all at once.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide fiddle of the same, So that the error can be tracked easily

Comment: I updated question @Vish

Comment: Okay so let me confirm If I have understood correctly, You want the data to be fetched for the current view (It may be day,week or month), As and when you click on the next button for any of the view you want the data of that view, Is it the way you want?

Comment: exactly, like pagination while getting data from API

Comment: I can give you a simple solution,  Which I created for my students, See if it helpful to you, give me a moment

Answer (score 1):

Controller.js Code:            .

```
$scope.getEvents = function(){
            var obj = {};
            $scope.events = [];
            obj.startDate = new Date($scope.myView.intervalStart).getTime();
            obj.endDate = new Date($scope.myView.intervalEnd).getTime();

        if($scope.myView.name == "month"){
            obj.endDate = obj.endDate - 19801000;
        }
       //Give a call to database from here, in which obj contains
       // start and end of the view

        var getEventsPromise = masterCalendarAPI.getEvents(obj);
        getEventsPromise.then(function (response) {
            if(response.statusCode == 200){
               //Assign $scope.event the list object retrieved from database
           }
        },
        function (error) {
           console.log(error);
        });
    }

//Remember this method will be called on each view change with all details in 'view' object
     $scope.renderView = function (view) {
            $scope.myView = view;
            $scope.getEvents();
        } 

    $scope.uiConfig = {
                calendar: {
                    height: 500,
                    editable: false,
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next title',
                        center: '',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    eventLimit: true,
                    views: {
                        month: {
                            eventLimit:3
                        }
                        },
                    columnFormat:'dddd',
                    timezone: 'local',
                    timeFormat: 'hh:mm a',
                    titleFormat:'MMMM D, YYYY',
                    slotDuration:'00:30:00',
                    eventRender:$scope.eventRender,
                    eventClick: $scope.eventClicked,
                    dayClick: $scope.dayClick,
                    eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
                    eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
                    viewRender: $scope.renderView
                }
            } ;
//event sources array
    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
```

Comment: //Assign $scope.event the list object retrieved from database
$scope.managedEvents = data // data returned from database
but it is not loading into calendar

Comment: Plz share your sample solution

Comment: Show me your 'data' object which you are retrieving from the database

Comment: added in question

Comment: Satish if you provide me fiddle or plunker, I can solve your problem easily..!! :)